# Is there a way to auto load data to a dataset in PowerApps Component Framework (PCF)?

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, powerapps-component-framework

I am using the following DataSet Grid example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/component-framework/sample-controls/data-set-grid-control

The example allows me to upload a *DataSet* and then shows it into a *grid*.

I am trying to upload this *DataSet* through ***code*** to be loaded **automatically on startup** instead of doing it manually.

Is there a way to do do?

*UPDATE:*

**My use case:** I am willing to create a PCF component and use it on *Dynamics CRM* to generate a view for cases.
I need the component to retrieve the cases from the CRM on startup so I can apply some logic on it and show it in the view. So far I can upload it **manually** and apply the logic.

Comment: Can you explain your use case?

Comment: I am willing to create a PCF component and use it on Dynamics CRM to generate a view for cases. I need the component to retrieve the cases from the CRM on startup so I can apply some logic on it and show it in the view. So far I can upload it manually and apply the logic. @ArunVinoth

Comment: Any follow up questions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the PCF control harness scenario, debugging/testing the control with mock data. This is how it’s designed, to upload the mock data while testing. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/component-framework/debugging-custom-controls#test-code-components-with-mock-data)

> For dataset type components, you can load a CSV file with test data. You manually create or export in .csv format directly from your environment. Once a valid CSV file is available, it can be loaded

Once you upload the control in CRM, after entity/view configuration is done - then the control will render dynamic records from the CRM view based on existing filter criteria. The PCF component is just rendering a new UX/UI on top of existing data.